# Kotlin coroutines and Spring Framework 5 reactive types

Tags: spring, kotlin, coroutine, spring-webflux, kotlinx.coroutines

Kotlin coroutines allow to execute non-blocking code by returning `Deferred` value. This is really useful to make non-blocking code while using blocking methods (from a library for example).

Spring 5 allows to use `Mono` and `Flux` into the framework. The big interest that I see is the ability to *serialize* instances of these two types and send it back as response when someone call a controller endpoint.

One of the big point of Spring 5 is to have an specific support for Kotlin (router, bean declaration, ...), but I cannot find informations about the possible interactions between Kotlin coroutines and Spring 5 reactive types.

Is there any way to combine the advantages of these features?

- converting `Deferred` into `Mono`/`Flux`?
- having a `Deferred` as response type of Spring controller methods ?

If no, in which cases do coroutine make sense if we have Spring 5 reactive types?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of version 5.2 (still work in progress), Spring Framework provides official support for coroutines. I have written [a detailed blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow) that explains how `Mono` and `Flux` types map to suspending functions, `Deferred` and Kotlin `Flow` types. You can also find more details in the [coroutines section of Spring Framework 5.2 reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#coroutines).

Comment: Thanks for your fast and nice response! I will give a try to the Reactor Core support in kotlinx.coroutines, and check Projet Loom.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the blog post and documentation of Spring official support for coroutines which will available in Spring Framework 5.2.